# Duda acerca del uso de LocalDateTime Java

Tags: java, java-8

Quería saber si es posible hacer que la fecha en este caso el dia se actualice automáticamente al sumar segundos, minutos o horas, porque no me ha sido posible realizarlo, por ejemplo tengo: `LocalDateTime hfEntrada = LocalDateTime.of(fechaActual, hEntrada);` en donde hora de entrada es una hora definida previamente, lo que intento hacer es que cuando sume minutos, horas, o segundos a hfEntrada y esta pase las 00:00, me actualice el día automáticamente.

Es decir si por ejemplo tengo una fecha como "2019-11-24T23:00", y al sumar por ejemplo 70 minutos pueda obtener "2019-11-25T00:10", pero lo que obtengo es "2019-11-24T00:10", la misma fecha, y la hora correcta. 
Los minutos los sumo con `hfEntrada.plusMinutes(70);`.

Se agradecería cualquier ayuda que me puedan ofrecer.

Comment: Muestra el código sobre el cual estás trabajando pulsando en [edit]. Gracias.

Comment: Lo que muestra hasta ahora funciona perfectamente sin probarlo. Solo ten en cuenta que la llamada a ese método no modifica el estado del objeto sobre el que se llama, sino que genera un nuevo objeto con el valor modificado. Quizás estás esperando que esta llamada te modifica el valor de la variable `hfEntrada`.

Answer (score 1):

No sé como lo estás haciendo pero `.plusMinutes()` funciona correctamente como lo quieres:

```
LocalDateTime a = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-11-24T23:00");
LocalDateTime b = a.plusMinutes(70);        
System.out.println(a);        
System.out.println(b);
```

**output**

```
2019-11-24T23:00
2019-11-25T00:10
```